# How do I tell if a user account is already logged in using ASP.Net Forms Authentication?

Tags: asp.net, security, forms-authentication

Our SSO login process uses Forms Authentication against a custom user store in SQL Server.

One of our new security requirements is to only allow an account to have one active session at a time. So any time a user logs in, we will check to see if the login credentials are already active, and preferably prevent the new user from logging in again until the other session ends. Alternatively we could force the other session to end, if that would be easier to implement.

Is there a simple way to do this with Forms Authentication? We've considered a custom approach where we track each session in the database, but it would be a lot of work and we'd probably have to modify all of our applications to detect the session_end, which I'm hoping to avoid. I figure there has to be something in Forms Auth that handles this.

I've seen the MembershipUser.IsOnline() method, which seems ideal, but we're not using a Membership provider.

UPDATE: Just to be clear, I do not need to check whether the current user is logged in, I need to know if somebody else is already logged in using the same account.

Comment: This was a while back, but I see that it's become a notable question, so I'll share my solution - we ended up doing a custom approach along the lines of what Kb. suggested, basically tracking user activity in the database. For each user we'd store a last login date and a session key. The key was generated and stored when the user logged in, then we'd check the current key on every page. 


If the current user's key ever didn't match the one in the database, we'd invalidate their session and instantly log them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correct, you would need to store the last activity state based on the user id.
Membership.IsOnline() is implemented by checking the [LastActivityDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.lastactivitydate.aspx) property persisted in the membership database.
So somewhere, you would need to track user activity.
 
You could maybe implement a httpmodule that updates a timestamp for user activity.

Comment: Hm, an httpmodule is an interesting idea. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

Answer (score 2):

If the `HttpContext.Current.User` property is not null then they are logged in.  And `Identity.IsAuthenticated` is true.