# What is the best practice for limiting ASP.NET user sessions to a single active session?

Tags: asp.net, session, asp.net-membership

I have a requirement where a logged-in user can only have 1 active session at a time in an ASP.NET application.  Currently a single user can log in from multiple machines simultaneously and get multiple sessions.  I am using standard ASP.NET Membership with AppFabric for session state management.  Am I missing some basic switch available in ASP.NET Membership to enforce this?  Otherwise, the plan was to add a table to the membership database that would have the aspnet_Users.UserId and sessionId columns and simply make sure that the current session Id (last-in) is the only session allowed.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I tell if a user account is already logged in using ASP.Net Forms Authentication?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516802/how-do-i-tell-if-a-user-account-is-already-logged-in-using-asp-net-forms-authent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up correlating the latest session Id to the user's profile in the database after a successful login using a custom table.  This correlated session Id value is checked using an HttpModule for each request.  If the user's current session Id doesn't match the saved Id, then they are redirected to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as simply as saving the last login time in your user table.  Save the same information in your users' session state at login.

Check to see if the times match with each page request.  If the server has newer time in the user table when you compare, you know you are no longer in the newest session for this user, and can either kill the current session by redirecting to a logout or kill the newer session by relogging in the current session.

Technically, this could be done with any piece of uniquely identifiable information for the session, such as a GUID, or even the session ID itself, but I like time, as it also gives something else you can measure against and find out, "How old is the current session?"

but... I typically like to see web apps run the way they were intended, which is where the user ID maintains the session, not the connection itself.  Users get absolutely livid when websites kick them out.  If you need to do it this way, be sure to have a good reason.. such as a subscription service (maybe streaming media) where only one device can access at a time or something similar.

Comment: We have to comply with the internal security auditing requirements, which are a mixture of OWASP Top Ten and some others as deemed important in the context of an enterprise application subject to HIPAA and PCI (Payment Card Industry) compliance.  So unfortunately this requirement is mandatory.

Answer (score -1):

It is best practice to not limit user sessions to a single active session.

The user's experience of this is "annoying site kicked me off again".

Associate the user's state with the user, not with the session.

Comment: Unfortunately, our corporate security test team had identified this as an important requirement and hence we have to comply to pass security auditing.